# Google Maps API - Text and Controls Too Small To Use on Mobile

Tags: api, text, air, maps

I am writing a mobile app in Adobe AIR that loads a google map using Javascript.  It works great on the desktop, but on mobile, everything looks WAY too tiny to be user friendly.  The street text is unreadable, the infoWindows are too small and text is too small, the icons are too small, the "Satellite" and "Maps" buttons are very tiny, the zoom in and zoom out buttons on the map are too small to manipulate.  Is there a "scale" property for the map that I am unable to find in the documentation that I can adjust to make a map more readable and user friendly?  Or is this a CSS issue?  Here is the Javascript I use to create the map, which I place in a div called "map":

```
function loadMap(latitude, longitude, mapWidth, mapHeight) {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var sheet = document.getElementById("map");
    sheet.style.width = String(mapWidth)+"px";
    sheet.style.height = String(mapHeight)+"px";
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing on my end. did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I asked this question 10 months ago so remember very little about the solution I came up with, but take a look at the code I posted below and let me know if that helps.  If not, I can dig a little deeper for you.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. I needed:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Answer (score 2):

It has been so long ago that I cannot remember the solution that I came up with. I took a quick look at the HTML file I created 10 months ago, and it looks like I created a header in my HTML file and it included some meta tags that included
content="initial-scale=1.0".  Try that and see if it helps.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed this at the top:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```